# How to render a sls pillar file in saltstack?

Tags: salt-stack

Is there a way I could render an sls file that resides in the pillar? Something more or less the equivalent of `state.show_sls`?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.pillar.html) module. You can check rendered pillar (or rather resulting data) by calling e.g.

```
$ salt '*' pillar.items
```

Or some particular part of the pillar e.g. elasticsearch:

```
$ salt '*' pillar.get elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 3):

See also the [slsutil.renderer](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.slsutil.html#salt.modules.slsutil.renderer) module:

```
salt '*' slsutil.renderer salt://path/to/file
salt '*' slsutil.renderer /path/to/file
salt '*' slsutil.renderer /path/to/file.jinja 'jinja'
salt '*' slsutil.renderer /path/to/file.sls 'jinja|yaml'
salt '*' slsutil.renderer string='Inline template! {{ saltenv }}'
salt '*' slsutil.renderer string='Hello, {{ name }}.' name='world'
```

For pillar sls files it may only work on the saltmaster. Example:

```
salt-call --local slsutil.renderer /srv/nacl/pillar/myservice/init.sls 'yamlex'
```